# How to change the api sdk version of my flutter android app

Tags: api, flutter, sdk, google-play

When I try to upload my new flutter application to the Google play, message comes telling that the app should be upgraded to the API sdk 29. My app has targeted sdk version 28. How can I convert targeted sdk from 28 to 29.
Are there any alternative solution without upgrading?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `android/app/gradle` file and change the sdk version to 29 and save it.
Then run `flutter clean` in terminal and then run your project once.
Make sure you are connected to internet.
Once i wasn't able to add a tag in manifest.xml bcz of lower sdk version and this solution worked for me.